# Pine Script: one long condition but loops through 5 different orderIDs to find a ID that isn't in a open position

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

one long condition but loops through 5 different strategy.orders to see which one isn't already in a trade with strategy.opentrades.order_id().

I cant just use pyramiding as I need a unique close condition per new strategy order

this code makes a list of open positions

```
orderIds = ""

for idx = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    strSuffix = idx == strategy.opentrades - 1 ? "" : ", "
    orderIds += strategy.opentrades.entry_id(idx) + strSuffix
```

I don't know how to loop through to see which positions IDs aren't open

```
if long condition
   loop 
   if orderIds != 1
   then use id 1
   else
      if orderIds != 2
      then use id 2
      else
         if orderIds != 3
         then use id 3
         else
```

=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use str.contains to find if an order ID is in the string

```
orderIds = ""

for idx = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
    strSuffix = idx == strategy.opentrades - 1 ? "" : ", "
    orderIds += strategy.opentrades.entry_id(idx) + strSuffix

//Show result on the chart
label.new(bar_index, high, orderIds)


// if your order ID is "1" then cakes = 12222 
cakes = 10000

if str.contains(orderIds, '1')
    cakes := 12222

plot(cakes)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, record your orderIds in a table and then loop througth this table.

You should use pinescript v5